# How do I maintain a constant amount of a good on an island via trade routes?

Tags: anno-2070

Is there way to set up trade routes to maintain a certain goods level? For example, if I have three islands where I might want to build, is it possible to set up a route to ensure that a certain island is always "topped up" to, say, 30 building modules but no more?

Comment: I believe you can do this via the interface to your warehouse, at least you could in other games.  With a limit set, you can send ships to a given island and they won't drop off goods if there's already enough there.

Comment: I know I can set lower limits. I didn't realize that I could set upper limits too. Will check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By right-clicking on goods in the warehouse or depot, you can set the minimum amount that is kept in stock.

Once you've set that, you can set a trade route to unload and then load from that port and it will keep the stock of that good at the amount you set as the minimum.

I did this in my sandbox game with just one "Building Materials" trade route. Using the Tycoon's ships that have 6 cargo holds, I had them set to unload then load the six types of building materials (building modules, tools, wood, concrete, glass, and steel) from each of my islands and had set a minimum on each island for these 6 goods. Set a handful of ships to the route and it worked pretty well.

Comment: Great! I had considered trying something like this but the idea of unloading and then reloading goods didn't occur to me. Thanks!